# Jenkins doesn't run build (Python, Selenium, Pytest)

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins, pytest

Guys maybe someone had the same problem, I'm new in Jenkins, and trying to run my first test in there, but stuck with problem, here is my error massage:

```
>                       os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
E                       selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: 
Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see 
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

../../shiningpanda/jobs/1c4a1d02/virtualenvs/d41d8cd9/lib/python3.5/site-
packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py:81: WebDriverException
=============================== warnings summary ========================
None
could not create cache path /Users/.cache/v/cache/lastfailed

-- Docs: http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html
===================== 1 warnings, 1 error in 0.41 seconds ================
Build step 'Virtualenv Builder' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani chromedriver is in PATH 100%
can you explain how to install chromedriver in Jenkins

Comment: just put this in built? `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:`

Comment: that was my PATH, how to set it in built?

Comment: You mean like: `PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:`

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani it works, thanks for help

Comment: Removed comments and updated answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can mean few things

**Chrome Driver not Installed**

This means that your Jenkin slave nodes don't have chrome driver installed, or they are not present in the PATH location variable folders

**PATH variables different**

It is possible that PATH variable for your build is not same as what you see in the terminal. So in your build script add the below

```
export PATH=<PATHFROMTERMINAL>
```

Or if you are using some plugin then set the environment variable option in that